# How can you have multiple fillDefaultValues scripts operating on one page?

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have a Web Part Page with multiple DVWP/New Item Forms for different lists. Each form contains a lookup field to one central list. I can get *one* form to auto-populate the lookup field with a query string using the **fillDefaultValues** script, but the other forms don't respond even when there are multiple scripts on the page.

Are there any tweaks to make to the script to populate multiple forms?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

// This javascript sets the default value of a lookup field identified 
// by <<FIELD DISPLAY NAME>> to the value stored in the querysting variable
// identified by <<QUERYSTRING VARIABLE NAME>>

// Customize this javascript by replacing <<FIELD DISPLAY NAME>> and 
// <<QUERYSTRING VARIABLE NAME>> with appropriate values.
// Then just paste it into NewForm.aspx inside PlaceHolderMain

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("fillDefaultValues");

function fillDefaultValues() {
  var qs = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);
  var args = qs.split("&");
  var vals = new Object();
  for (var i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
    var nameVal = args[i].split("=");
    var temp = unescape(nameVal[1]).split('+');
    nameVal[1] = temp.join(' ');
    vals[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
  }  
  setLookupFromFieldName("FIELD DISPLAY NAME", vals["QUERYSTRING VARIABLE NAME"]);
}

function setLookupFromFieldName(fieldName, value) {
  if (value == undefined) return;
  var theSelect = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("select","Lookup",fieldName);

// if theSelect is null, it means that the target list has more than
// 20 items, and the Lookup is being rendered with an input element

  if (theSelect == null) { 
    var theInput = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("input","",fieldName);
    ShowDropdown(theInput.id); 
    var opt=document.getElementById(theInput.opt);
    setSelectedOption(opt, value);
    OptLoseFocus(opt); //this function is provided by SharePoint 
  } else {
    setSelectedOption(theSelect, value);
  }
}

function setSelectedOption(select, value) {
  var opts = select.options;
  var l = opts.length;
  if (select == null) return;
  for (var i=0; i < l; i++) {
    if (opts[i].innerText == value) {
      select.selectedIndex = i;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle(tagName, identifier, title) {
  var len = identifier.length;
  var tags = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tempString = tags[i].id;
    if (tags[i].title == title && (identifier == "" || tempString.indexOf(identifier) == tempString.length - len)) {
      return tags[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle function returns after it finds the first matched element, so yeah, it would only set the first lookup.  I would try jQuery to do this as jQuery will return an array of matched elements.  Mark Rackley has a setLookup function which you can find [here](http://sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=4)